# using CloudWatch Events to trigger cron jobs on an EC2 instance overkill?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

We have an EC2 server that runs cronjobs. Currently there is a crontab on that server that holds the cronjob settings. Everything runs perfectly fine on this server.

Would it be overkill to use AWS Cloudwatch Events to trigger the crons instead? ie create a cloudwatch event that calls a lambda to run a shell command on the EC2 instance.

My thinking is that these would be possible benefits:

- no need to manage a crontab file on the EC2 server
- easier to activate/deactivate specific cronjobs

Comment: you could check also system manager service. It also supports command execution on EC2 and could be triggered by cloud watch event.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#SSM-Run-Command-event-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like there are indeed benefits according to the AWS Docs:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/

- Decouple job schedule and AMI: If your cron jobs are part of an AMI, each schedule change requires you to create a new AMI version, and update existing instances running with that AMI. This is both cumbersome and time-consuming. Using scheduled Lambda functions, you can keep the job schedule outside of your AMI and change the schedule on the fly.
- Flexible targeting of EC2 instances: By abstracting the job schedule from AMI and EC2 instances, you can flexibly target a subset of your EC2 instance fleet based on tags or other conditions. In this example, we are targeting EC2 instances with the “Environment=Dev” tag.
- Intelligent scheduling: With scheduled Lambda functions, you can add custom logic to you abstracted job scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's not an over kill at all. I have used same setup with great success running job(s) (around 50 different jobs) with heavy workload.

My setup was slightly different

The cloudwatch scheduled event was calling a lambda which in turn was putting a messages on a sqs and application in running on ec2 instance(s) was grabbing messages from the sqs and processing them.

The sqs was simply added for robustness.

But this may or may not make sense in your use case.